# Format certain rows after writing to excel file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have some code which compares two excel files and determines any new rows (new_rows) added or any rows which were deleted (dropped_rows).  It then uses xlsxwriter to write this to a excel sheet.  The bit of code I am having trouble with is that it is supposed to then iterate through the rows and if the row was a new row or a dropped row it is supposed to format it a certain way.  For whatever reason this part of the code isn't working correct and being ignored.

I've tried a whole host of different syntax to make this work but no luck.

**UPDATE**

After some more trial and error the issue seems to be caused by the index column.  It is a Case Number column and the values have a prefix like "Case_123, Case_456, Case_789, etc..".  This seems to be the root of the issue.  But not sure how to solve for it.

```
    grey_fmt = workbook.add_format({'font_color': '#E0E0E0'})
    highlight_fmt = workbook.add_format({'font_color': '#FF0000', 'bg_color':'#B1B3B3'})
    new_fmt = workbook.add_format({'font_color': '#32CD32','bold':True})

    # set format over range
    ## highlight changed cells
    worksheet.conditional_format('A1:J10000', {'type': 'text',
                                            'criteria': 'containing',
                                            'value':'→',
                                            'format': highlight_fmt})

    # highlight new/changed rows
    for row in range(dfDiff.shape[0]):
        if row+1 in newRows:
            worksheet.set_row(row+1, 15, new_fmt)
        if row+1 in droppedRows:
            worksheet.set_row(row+1, 15, grey_fmt)
```

the last part `# highlight new/changed rows` is the bit that is not working.  The conditional format portion works fine.

the rest of the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path


def excel_diff(path_OLD, path_NEW, index_col):

    df_OLD = pd.read_excel(path_OLD, index_col=index_col).fillna(0)
    df_NEW = pd.read_excel(path_NEW, index_col=index_col).fillna(0)

    # Perform Diff
    dfDiff = df_NEW.copy()
    droppedRows = []
    newRows = []

    cols_OLD = df_OLD.columns
    cols_NEW = df_NEW.columns
    sharedCols = list(set(cols_OLD).intersection(cols_NEW))

    for row in dfDiff.index:
        if (row in df_OLD.index) and (row in df_NEW.index):
            for col in sharedCols:
                value_OLD = df_OLD.loc[row,col]
                value_NEW = df_NEW.loc[row,col]
                if value_OLD==value_NEW:
                    dfDiff.loc[row,col] = df_NEW.loc[row,col]
                else:
                    dfDiff.loc[row,col] = ('{}→{}').format(value_OLD,value_NEW)
        else:
            newRows.append(row)

    for row in df_OLD.index:
        if row not in df_NEW.index:
            droppedRows.append(row)
            dfDiff = dfDiff.append(df_OLD.loc[row,:])

    dfDiff = dfDiff.sort_index().fillna('')
    print(dfDiff)
    print('\nNew Rows:     {}'.format(newRows))
    print('Dropped Rows: {}'.format(droppedRows))

    # Save output and format
    fname = '{} vs {}.xlsx'.format(path_OLD.stem,path_NEW.stem)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fname, engine='xlsxwriter')

    dfDiff.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='DIFF', index=True)
    df_NEW.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=path_NEW.stem, index=True)
    df_OLD.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=path_OLD.stem, index=True)

    # get xlsxwriter objects
    workbook  = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['DIFF']
    worksheet.hide_gridlines(2)
    worksheet.set_default_row(15)

    # define formats
    date_fmt = workbook.add_format({'align': 'center', 'num_format': 'yyyy-mm-dd'})
    center_fmt = workbook.add_format({'align': 'center'})
    number_fmt = workbook.add_format({'align': 'center', 'num_format': '#,##0.00'})
    cur_fmt = workbook.add_format({'align': 'center', 'num_format': '$#,##0.00'})
    perc_fmt = workbook.add_format({'align': 'center', 'num_format': '0%'})
    grey_fmt = workbook.add_format({'font_color': '#E0E0E0'})
    highlight_fmt = workbook.add_format({'font_color': '#FF0000', 'bg_color':'#B1B3B3'})
    new_fmt = workbook.add_format({'font_color': '#32CD32','bold':True})

    # set format over range
    ## highlight changed cells
    worksheet.conditional_format('A1:J10000', {'type': 'text',
                                            'criteria': 'containing',
                                            'value':'→',
                                            'format': highlight_fmt})

    # highlight new/changed rows
    for row in range(dfDiff.shape[0]):
        if row+1 in newRows:
            worksheet.set_row(row+1, 15, new_fmt)
        if row+1 in droppedRows:
            worksheet.set_row(row+1, 15, grey_fmt)

    # save
    writer.save()
    print('\nDone.\n')


def main():
    path_OLD = Path('file1.xlsx')
    path_NEW = Path('file2.xlsx')

    # get index col from data
    df = pd.read_excel(path_NEW)
    index_col = df.columns[0]
    print('\nIndex column: {}\n'.format(index_col))

    excel_diff(path_OLD, path_NEW, index_col)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: According to [this](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html), worksheet.set_row accepts parameter `row` which is zero-indexed. Perhaps check whether `newRows` and `droppedRows` are zero-indexed as well.

Comment: I believe so.  I added the rest of the code to the original post.  It should be working.